# Using variables in SAS User defined function

Tags: sas

I am a beginner SAS user with much experience in VBA and am having a hard time figuring out User defined functions in SAS.

I am having several problems using variables in User defined functions, but I think the two listed below are probably a related issue and would likely solve the rest of them.

I)  How do you use a variable in a macro function from within a user defined function?

```
proc fcmp outlib = sasuser.funcs.trial;
    function testNumbers(testvar $) $;
        length testing $ 100;
        lencheck = %length(testvar);
        return (lencheck);
    endsub;
run;
options cmplib = sasuser.funcs;
%put %sysfunc(testnumbers(short));
```

No matter what the input to the function is, the result is always 7, which matches the length of the input variable name "testvar"  If I change the variable name, it changes the result.  I've tried putting an ampersand in front of the variable name, but this doesn't work (it just makes the result 8...).  I can get the function to return the input by putting in "return (testvar)" but can't figure out how to get the length function to work.

II)  How do you define a variable as numeric in the context of the user defined function?

```
 proc fcmp outlib=sasuser.funcs.trial;
     function testNumbers(testvar $) $;
           length testvar $ 100;
           myNumber = 5
           testNum = put(myNumber, 2.);

           tempPath = %substr(1234567890, 3, 2)
           tempPath1 = %substr(1234567890, 3, myNumber)
           tempPath2 = %substr(1234567890, 3, testNum)
           tempPath3 = %substr(1234567890, 3, put(myNumber, 2.))

           return (tempPath);
     endsub;
 run;
```

The first tempPath works and returns "34" as expected.  But tempPath1, tempPath2 and tempPath3 all return errors.  The error is that Argument 3 to macro function %substr is not a number.  For tempPath3 there is an additional error that a required operateor not found in the expression.

Note:  I am aware that these functions do not do anything worthwhile.  These are simplified as I am trying to learn the language and the possibilities.  There may be other problems even with the simple code provided, and any advice on that would be appreciated.

What I was actually trying to code was a function that will allow for dynamically changing the library being used (so if a temp flag is set, everything will go into the Work directory, but if not, it will go to the final production location).  If there is a better solution than a UDF for this, I'd love to hear this too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The macro processor evaluates before the results are passed onto base SAS for processing.

Since your program uses this macro logic.

```
lencheck = %length(testvar);
```

The macro processor will calculate `%length(testvar)` which is 7 since that is how many characters are in the string `testvar`. It is the same as if wrote this statement:

```
lencheck = 7 ;
```

If you want the function to find the length of the variable `TESTVAR` then you need to use the `LENGTH()` function and not the macro function `%LENGTH()`.

You have a similar issue with your use of the `%SUBSTR()` macro function instead of the function `SUBSTR()` in your second example.

Comment: I had a feeling I was doing something silly.  Thanks for the clear explanation of the processing order and resolution!!

Comment: @OpiesDad Actually - use the `lengthn()` function.  The `length()` function returns a value of 1 for empty strings.  `lengthn()` will return the expected value of zero.  You may also want to look into the `substrn()` function as well.

Comment: @RobertPenridge Thanks!  For the particular function I'm currently writing, it doesn't matter, but that will surely save a bunch of headaches later when it inevitably will.  :)